# how can i replace a string with retrieved XML values

Tags: c#, xml, replace

**Langauge : C#**

I wrote an SQL stored procedure which returns an xml output value

**xml value :**

```
<row CPName="MyCp" ServiceName="SongWriter" NumberOfContentDaysLeft="3" ServiceShortCode="12345" />
<row CPName="Unknown" ServiceName="Not Available" NumberOfContentDaysLeft="0" ServiceShortCode="698562" />
```

I have a string defined in my code as below

```
string message = "<CpName>: <ServiceName> Content will finish in <NumberOfContentDaysLeft> please send 1 to <ServiceShortCode>";
```

I want to replace the text of the message by the xml values retrieved from the stored procedure. (`<CpName>` in the message will be replaced by the text **"MyCp"** from the xml)

for example taking into consideration one xml record the message text would be: (The text in bold is the replaced text)

**MyCp**: **SongWriter** Content will finish in **3** please send 1 to **12345**

Any suggestions on how to do that or if there is a better approach.

Comment: Do you have the backend properties holding the values for CPName, ServiceName, NumberOfContentDaysLeft and ServiceShortCode? You'd just do a String.Replace or String.Format to create a new message

Comment: @nayef There are a few steps to achieve that i.e 1. get list of attributes to be queried from the XML, 2. actually querying those attribute values, 3. replace templates in the string which is in form of `<attribute_name>` with the actual value retrieved from the XML. Explain which part you're having trouble with, and post how you did the other parts. Thanks

Comment: my problem is in the first step (getting the list of attributes to be queried from the XML).

Comment: Is the xml you posted the complete xml?  Need to know because standard xml has only one root tag and you have an array of root tags.